# Can someone else use your deceased brother’s green card?

Tags: immigration, is-x-legal

I just found out that my brother-in-law used my deceased brother’s green card.  Is this legal?

Comment: Ah, no; why do you think that *would* be legal?

Comment: Do you suppose it'd be legal to use his passport, or driver's license, or social security number, or any other form of government-issued document that's issued to a specific person?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question shows not even an attempt to google the question.

Answer (score 4):

You ask if your deceased brother's green card may be legally used by another person.

The answer is: no.

Answer (score 1):

18 U.S. Code § 1546.Fraud and misuse of visas, permits, and other documents

> (b)Whoever uses— (1)an identification document, knowing (or having
> reason to know) that the document was not issued lawfully for the use
> of the possessor, (2)an identification document knowing (or having
> reason to know) that the document is false, or (3)a false attestation,
> for the purpose of satisfying a requirement of section 274A(b) of the
> Immigration and Nationality Act, shall be fined under this title,
> imprisoned not more than 5 years, or both.

Full code text [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1546).